# android cookiestore cannot remove null cookie

Tags: java, android, oop, cookies

My first question on Stackoverflow, I apologize if I duplicate question or has wrong format :)

I am trying to recreate a cookie store from shared reference, and there is always a null cookie when I print the cookie store in log. Because it works when I use same cookie store, I was wondering if this null cookie causes my http get to give a no-login response. If so, how can I remove it?

```
public void login(){
    // after login succeed 
    CookieStore store = client.getCookieStore();
    List<Cookie> cookie_list = COOKIES.getCookies();
    //
    Log(1);
    //
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences();
    prefs.edit().putString(COOKIE_SESSION_NAME,cookie_list.get(0).toString()).commit();
}

public void getData(){
    DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    CookieStore store = client.getCookieStore();`enter code here`
    //
    Log(2);
    //
    store.clear();
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences();
    String cookieStr =  prefs.getString(COOKIE_SESSION_ID, Configs.INVALID);
    BasicClientCookie cookie =  new BasicClientCookie(COOKIE_SESSION_ID,cookieStr);
    store.addCookie(cookie);
    //
    Log(3);
    //
    client.setCookieStore(store);

    // http get from here
```

}

and this is what the logs look like:

```
Log(1):
[[version: 0][name: ASP.NET_SessionId][value: 123456][domain: example.com][path: /][expiry: null],
[version: 0][name: .ASPXAUTH][value:123456] [domain: example.com][path: /][expiry: Fri Apr 18 09:36:06 EDT 2014]]

Log(2):
[]

Log(3):
[[version: 0][name: ASP.NET_SessionId][value: 123456][domain: example.com][path: /][expiry: null],
[version: 0][name: .ASPXAUTH][value:123456] [domain: example.com][path: /][expiry: Fri Apr 18 09:36:06 EDT 2014]]
[domain: null][path: null][expiry: null]
```